# Empty webmap using QGIS2web plugin on SharePoint site

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, web-mapping, qgis2web, sharepoint

I can produce my webmap using the qgis2web plugin without a problem. When the index.html file is created I click on the index.html file and the webmap opens and I can see my map content. So far so good.

Now, in the next step I want to add/embed/view this webmap on my SharePoint site.

I tried several attempts.

- Load the whole gis folder including all subfolders and the index.html file to a sharepoint library and then click on the index.html file again. It opens, but it is a bank page. When I open the index.html in my Windows Explorer then I can see the map. But it is empty via SharePoint...
- I tried to rename the index.html to index.aspx. When I click on it, it automatically downloads the file without viewing it.
- I tried to export as leaflet and as OpenLayers but both result in an empty webmap on SharePoint again but perfectly fine in the explorer.
- I tried to export with FTP protocol (instead to the folder option) but got stuck.

So, is there a way to either view my map which is perfectly presented in a web map that is stored on my C-drive but not on sharepoint, or if there is a way to export to FTP and if yes, do you know what to do?

And/or maybe you know how to modify a filepath C:/// to a HTTPS link on SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this route?
How to host static HTML sites on modern SharePoint site collections
https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2022/02/07/host-static-html-sites-modern-sharepoint-site-collections/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/236346)